# Placing IntelliJ plugin in status bar

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm just starting playing around with the plugin SDK for IntelliJ IDEA. However I already have some trouble with the first step.

I'd like to place an action in the lower status bar, next to the Git actions.

How can I place that action there?

[image: Screenshot showing desired position]

Comment: look how the existing ones are implemented?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying. Looked at the source code of "git4idea" plugin. However, I have difficulties understanding how they put the plugin there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of UI is called `EditorBasedWidget`. If you like to explore how it works in `git4idea` plugin, I can suggest you to start with `GitBranchWidget` and `DvcsStatusWidget` classes.

Here is the code for the simplest example:

**MyWidget.java**

```
public class MyWidget extends EditorBasedWidget {
    public MyWidget(@NotNull Project project) {
        super(project);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String ID() {
        return "MyWidget";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WidgetPresentation getPresentation(@NotNull PlatformType type) {
        return new MyPresentation();
    }
}
```

**MyPresentation.java**

```
public class MyPresentation implements StatusBarWidget.MultipleTextValuesPresentation {
    @Nullable("null means the widget is unable to show the popup")
    @Override
    public ListPopup getPopupStep() {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getSelectedValue() {
        return "Selected value";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getMaxValue() {
        return "Max value";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getTooltipText() {
        return "Tooltip text";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Consumer<MouseEvent> getClickConsumer() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Somewhere, for example in `ProjectComponent`**

```
ApplicationManager.getApplication().invokeLater(() -> {
    StatusBar statusBar = WindowManager.getInstance().getStatusBar(myProject);
    if (statusBar != null) {
       statusBar.addWidget(new MyWidget(myProject));
    }
});
```

And here is the result:

[image]